# Show that $|x-a| < \epsilon$ implies $|a| - \epsilon < |x| < |a| + \epsilon$.

Tags: inequality

For any real numbers $x$, $a$, and $\epsilon >0$, show that $|x-a| < \epsilon$ implies $|a| - \epsilon < |x| < |a| + \epsilon$.

I can prove this graphically by visualizing the points on a number line, but I was wondering if my following algebraic proof is correct.

We know that $-|x-a| \le |x|-|a| \le |x-a|$, so $|x| - |a| \le |x-a| < \epsilon \implies |x| < |a| + \epsilon$. Likewise, $-|x-a| \le |x| - |a| \implies |a|-|x| \le |x-a| < \epsilon \implies |a| - \epsilon < |x|$.

So, together we have: $|a| - \epsilon < |x| < |a| + \epsilon$.

Comment: You've reproved the triangle inequality, 2nd form: $$\bigl||x|-|a|\bigr|\le |x-a|.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$|x|=|x-a+a|$$
$$\leq |x-a|+|a|<\epsilon+|a|$$

$$|a|=|x-a-x|$$
$$\le |x-a|+|x|<\epsilon+|x |$$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof relies on $-|x-a|\le|x|-|a|\le|x-a|$ (which should be proved, but is easy).

You can do differently. From $|x-a|<\varepsilon$ we get
$$
a-\varepsilon<x<a+\varepsilon
$$
Since $a+\varepsilon\le|a|+\varepsilon$ and $a-\varepsilon\ge-|a|-\varepsilon$, we obtain
$$
-|a|-\varepsilon<x<|a|+\varepsilon
$$
On the other hand, the initial inequality can be rewritten as
$$
-a-\varepsilon<-x<-a+\varepsilon
$$
and, with the same argument as before, we get
$$
-|a|-\varepsilon<-x<|a|+\varepsilon
$$